# Implementation of glass filter for images

Tags: java, beginner

This is exercise 3.1.39. from the book *Computer Science An Interdisciplinary Approach* by Sedgewick & Wayne:

> Write a program that takes the name of an image file as a command-line
> argument and applies a glass filter: set each pixel p to the color of
> a random neighboring pixel (whose pixel coordinates both differ from
> p’s coordinates by at most 5).

Here is my program:

```
import java.awt.Color;

public class test 
{
    public static int[] chooseRandomNeighbor(int i, int j)
    {
        int[] chosenNeighbor = new int[2];
        double r = Math.random();
        if      (r < 1.0/8.0)
        {
            chosenNeighbor[0] = i-1;
            chosenNeighbor[1] = j-1;
        }
        else if (r < 2.0/8.0)
        {
            chosenNeighbor[0] = i-1;
            chosenNeighbor[1] = j; 
        }
        else if (r < 3.0/8.0)
        {
            chosenNeighbor[0] = i-1;
            chosenNeighbor[1] = j+1; 
        }
        else if (r < 4.0/8.0)
        {
            chosenNeighbor[0] = i;
            chosenNeighbor[1] = j+1; 
        }
        else if (r < 5.0/8.0)
        {
            chosenNeighbor[0] = i+1;
            chosenNeighbor[1] = j+1; 
        }
        else if (r < 6.0/8.0)
        {
            chosenNeighbor[0] = i+1;
            chosenNeighbor[1] = j; 
        }
        else if (r < 7.0/8.0)
        {
            chosenNeighbor[0] = i+1;
            chosenNeighbor[1] = j-1; 
        }
        else if (r < 8.0/8.0)
        {
            chosenNeighbor[0] = i;
            chosenNeighbor[1] = j-1; 
        }
        return chosenNeighbor;
    }
    public static Picture filter(Picture picture)
    {
        int width = picture.width();
        int height = picture.height();
        Picture filteredPicture = new Picture(width,height);
        // the following four for-loops make the dead frame
        for (int row = 0; row < height; row++)
        {
            Color color = picture.get(0,row);
            filteredPicture.set(0,row,color);
        }
        for (int row = 0; row < height; row++)
        {
            Color color = picture.get(width-1,row);
            filteredPicture.set(width-1,row,color);
        }
        for (int col = 0; col < width; col++)
        {
            Color color = picture.get(col,0);
            filteredPicture.set(col,0,color);
        }
        for (int col = 0; col < width; col++)
        {
            Color color = picture.get(col,height-1);
            filteredPicture.set(col,height-1,color);
        }
        // the real filtering takes place here
        for (int col = 1; col < width-1; col++)
        {
            for (int row = 1; row < height-1; row++)
            {
                int[] chosenNeighbor = chooseRandomNeighbor(row,col);
                Color color = picture.get(chosenNeighbor[1],chosenNeighbor[0]);
                filteredPicture.set(col,row,color);
            }
        }
        return filteredPicture;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Picture picture = new Picture(args[0]);
        Picture filteredPicture = filter(filter(filter(filter(picture))));
        filteredPicture.show();
    }
}
```

[Picture](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/javadoc/Picture.html) is a simple API written by the authors of the book. I checked my program and it works. Here is one instance of it:

Input (picture of James McAvoy taken from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_McAvoy#/media/File:James_McAvoy_by_Gage_Skidmore_2.jpg) who played in the movie [Glass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glass_(2019_film))):

[image]

Output:

[image]

Is there any way that I can improve my program?

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting exercise and nice implementation, few suggestions on my side:

- The method `chooseRandomNeighbor` is only used by `filter`, so it can be set to `private`
- The name `filter` is too general for a method, a better name might be `applyGlassFilter`
- In Java the name of a class starts with a capital letter

### Optimization

> random neighboring pixel (whose pixel coordinates both differ from p’s
> coordinates by at most 5).

The method `chooseRandomNeighbor` picks an adjacent random neighbor (which differ by at most 1) and then gets called 4 times. That implies creating 4 full images in memory. Wouldn't be better to directly pick a neighbor with maximum distance 5?

To do that the method `chooseRandomNeighbor` needs to accept the width or height:

```
int neighborColIndex = chooseRandomNeighbor(col,width);
int neighborRowIndex = chooseRandomNeighbor(row,height);
```

And this is `chooseRandomNeighbor` refactored:

```
private static int chooseRandomNeighbor(int index, int max) {
    // Random delta between -5 and +5
    int randomDelta = (int) ((Math.random() * (10)) - 5);
    // Add delta to index without overflowing the limit
    int neighborIndex = (index + randomDelta) % max;
    // If index is negative return 0
    return neighborIndex < 0 ? 0 : neighborIndex;
}
```

Now the method `filter` can be called only once and only the new image will be created in memory.

**Side note**: you are getting better and better, keep up the good work!

### Code Refactored

```
public class Test {
    
    public static Picture applyGlassFilter(Picture inputPicture) {
        int width = inputPicture.width();
        int height = inputPicture.height();
        Picture outputPicture = new Picture(width, height);
        for (int col = 0; col < width; col++) {
            for (int row = 0; row < height; row++) {
                int neighborColIndex = chooseRandomNeighbor(col,width);
                int neighborRowIndex = chooseRandomNeighbor(row,height);
                Color c = inputPicture.get(neighborColIndex,neighborRowIndex);
                outputPicture.set(col, row, c);
            }
        }
        return outputPicture;
    }
    
    private static int chooseRandomNeighbor(int index, int max) {
        // Random delta between -5 and +5
        int randomDelta = (int) ((Math.random() * (10)) - 5);
        // Add delta to index without overflowing the limit
        int neighborIndex = (index + randomDelta) % max;
        // If index is negative return 0
        return neighborIndex < 0 ? 0 : neighborIndex;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Picture inputPicture = new Picture(args[0]);
        Picture outputPicture = applyGlassFilter(inputPicture);
        outputPicture.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Also appreciate the "side note". It's nice to have feedback sometimes.